# It can't Pass the boolean Function

Tags: vb.net

The code seems to be very good and nice organizing also the order follow is good, so where is the problem?

It never reaches to msgbox("2") ...

```
     Public Function savefnn() As Boolean
    If tco.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Select Product")
        tco.Focus()
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Bags" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf ttype.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Type")
            ttype.Focus()
        ElseIf Tcolor.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Color")
            Tcolor.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Balls" Then
        If ttype.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Type")
            ttype.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Blades" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf ttype.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Type")
            ttype.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Glues" Or tco.Text = "Cleaners" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf tsize.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Size")
            tsize.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Rubbers" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf Tcolor.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Color")
            Tcolor.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Shoes" Or tco.Text = "Socks" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf tsize.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Size")
            tsize.Focus()
        ElseIf Tcolor.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Color")
            Tcolor.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Shorts" Or tco.Text = "TShirts" Or tco.Text = "Towels" Or tco.Text = "TrainigSuits" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        ElseIf tsize.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Size")
            tsize.Focus()
        ElseIf Tcolor.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Choose Color")
            Tcolor.Focus()
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Tables" Or tco.Text = "Nets" Then
        If tname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Name")
            tname.Focus()
        End If
    Else

        Return True

    End If

End Function
Public Function isrecordvalid() As Boolean
    If tco.Text = "Bags" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' And [Type] LIKE '%" & ttype.Text & "%' And [Color] LIKE '%" & Tcolor.Text & "%' ", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Balls" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [Type] LIKE '%" & ttype.Text & "%' ", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Blades" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' And [Type] LIKE '%" & ttype.Text & "%' ", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Glues" Or tco.Text = "Cleaners" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' And [Size] LIKE '%" & tsize.Text & "%'", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Shoes" Or tco.Text = "Socks" Or tco.Text = "Shorts" Or tco.Text = "TShirts" Or tco.Text = "Towels" Or tco.Text = "TrainingSuits" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' And [Size] LIKE '%" & tsize.Text & "%' And [Color] LIKE '%" & Tcolor.Text & "%'", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Rubbers" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' And [Color] LIKE '%" & Tcolor.Text & "%'", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    ElseIf tco.Text = "Tables" Or tco.Text = "Nets" Then
        Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AllProducts] WHERE [ProductName] LIKE '%" & tname.Text & "%' ", cnxnString)
        Dim mytable As New DataTable
        myadapter.Fill(mytable)
        If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Product Is Already Saved", vbCritical, "Error")
        End If
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
Private Sub bs_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bs.Click
    MsgBox("1")
    If savefnn() = True Then
        MsgBox("2")
        If isrecordvalid() = True Then
            MsgBox("3")
            con.Open()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM AllProducts"
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            da.Fill(ds, "AllProducts")
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            con.Close()
            start = System.DateTime.Now.ToString
            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            cb.QuotePrefix = "["
            cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
            dsNewRow = ds.Tables("AllProducts").NewRow()
            dsNewRow.Item("Product") = tco.Text
            If tname.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("ProductName") = tname.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("ProductName") = "None"
            End If
            If Button2.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("Image") = Label40.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("Image") = "None"
            End If
            If tch.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("Charac") = tch.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("Charac") = "None"
            End If
            If ttype.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("Type") = ttype.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("Type") = "None"
            End If
            If tsize.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("Size") = tsize.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("Size") = "None"
            End If
            If Tcolor.Enabled = True Then
                dsNewRow.Item("color") = Tcolor.Text
            Else
                dsNewRow.Item("Color") = "None"
            End If
            dsNewRow.Item("Date") = start
            ds.Tables("AllProducts").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
            da.Update(ds, "AllProducts")
            s = 1
            MsgBox("New Product Saved")
            store = tname.Text
            store1 = start
            bus.Enabled = True
            clear1()
            MsgBox("4")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One of the easiest ways to solve these types of issues is to put a breakpiont at the start of the code - then you can step through the code and inspect the values being tested to see what's happening (or not happening) and why.

Comment: Your functions don't have `Return` values on all code paths. Also: [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx).

Comment: There is a return value !!!!

Comment: The `Else` block where you have your only `Return` is only executed if all of the other `If`/`ElseIf` do not evaluate to `True`.

Comment: most of those inner IFs look wrong - you only want Name OR Size OR color?

Comment: If you put another message box at the end of bs_Click, does it get there?  I suspect that it's actually throwing an exception somewhere and skipping the rest of everything.  You _should_ have returns in the other cases and use Select Case like many others have suggested here, but I think your point is that if everything is valid, it _should_ be getting to the one `Return True` statement and must not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use 'SWITCH CASE' instead of nested 'IF'.

Performance of program would be improved and you could have better clearance on logic as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are not reaching  MsgBox("2") because your function savefnn() is not returning true. In scenarios where you are not getting the expected results you can use **[breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** in your code to debug it. You can also apply **[watch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx)** to find the current values.

And its better to use **Select Case** for the kind of nesting you are using.